# Objective-C: I want to compare / sort arrays in blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sorting, block

When sorting an array of character strings, I learned that sorting can be done easily with the following code.

```
arr = [arr sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector (localizedStandardCompare :)];
```

However, this time I want to rearrange the instance of the custom class.
* String information can be obtained from the instance method of the custom class.

So by returning `NSComparisonResult` using the following block sort
I thought that I could rearrange the instance of the custom class, but
It did not move as I expected.

```
- (NSArray <ObjectType> *) sortedArrayUsingComparator: (NSComparator) cmptr;
```

If you understand, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and include details of `cmptr` and anything it uses. Without knowing what your comparator is people cannot help you solve your issue that "it did not move as I expected".

Comment: `[array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(CustomClass *item1, CustomClass *item2) {`

Comment: The important thing is to order `@selector (localizedStandardCompare:)`!

Comment: Unfortunately your comments add little information. You need to edit the question (look at the bottom left under the tags and you can see `share edit close flag`, press `edit`) add the full block, the details of your `CustomClass` properties used, the order you get and the order you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Your Key" ascending:NO];
  NSArray *sortedArray=[yourArrayName sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```

Comment: It's always better to add some explanation to the answer just to make people understand what they are going to do

Comment: The important thing is to order @selector (localizedStandardCompare:)!

Comment: NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"yourkey contains[c] %@", sortingCharacter];
 NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p1]];

Please use this code of compare and sorting with case insensitive